# Python-printing the wrong way

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have entered the following code:

```
print("The new value for x is: ",x)
```

and the value of x is 9.

I expected that it will display something like: `The new value for x is:9`
but it displayed:

```
('The new value for x is: ', 9)
```

How can I fix that? also, my python version is:`2.7.13`

Comment: You *can* fix it with `print "The new value for x is:", x`. You *should* fix it by switching to Python 3.

Comment: @Delgan, while I agree that you should use `python 3` as a rule, there are still some reasons like some libraries that require you to use `python 2.7`. Besides, IMO it looks like he is just a beginner at programming (or at least in Python), so it does not matter much which version of python he uses as long as he is learning the basics

Comment: @Algosub Almost all libraries are supporting Python 3. Those that are not compatible are very old and are no longer maintained anyway, they likely have Python 3 equivalents. Only a codebase already consistent can justify the use of Python 2. Today there is absolutely no valid reason to start a new project in Python 2, even less when you are a beginner like the OP as you pointed out.

Comment: @Delgan, I do agree with your perspective in the argument on whether you *should* use python 2 or 3, I still think that for a beginner it's more important to understand the basics of programming, and not to become proficient in any specific language or syntax. but that's only an opinion :)

Comment: @Delgan, The reason that I'm not using Python 3 is that when I want to install it this error occurs: 0x80240017-Unspecified error.I couldn't fix it so I installed Python 2.also why do you recommend python3?

Comment: @FarzinNasiri Oh, that is unfortunate... Did you try to search on Google what could be the cause of this error? Python 3 is the latest version of Python, so it's not logical to install an older version while this one includes more thoughtful functions, new features, new libraries, a larger community, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `python 2.7` you do not use braces when calling print.
The correct syntax for printing a string with a parameter concatenated to it in  `python 2.7` would be:

```
print "The new value for x is: " + str(x)
```

The syntax you are using is the `python 3` syntax.

**Note**

As was stated in the comments by @ArpitSolanki, the code you used actually creates a tuple in `python 2.7`, and prints the result, hence you see the braces in the output.

Comment: The syntax has no problem. Paranthesis are valid but python 2 will interpret that you want to print a tuple. Also + is not needed `,` would work here.

Comment: Thanks @ArpitSolanki, that's correct. I just answered in a way that will help to do what the question asked.

Comment: Yeah it would help in current context but saying "current syntax for python2 would be" does not seem to be fair and i guess it's misleading also. If you can change that statement then it would be great.

Comment: You are correct @ArpitSolanki, done